# Using bootstrap columns but showing one component below the other

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, frontend

This is my html code:

```
<label>Search:</label>
<input type="text" id="list_search" class="form-control col-8">
<button class="btn btn-info col-2">Search</button>
```

You see my input tag has 8 columns and my button has 2.
Then I don't get **why** I'm getting this:

[image: Isn't supposed they should be X-aligned?]

Isn't supposed they should be X-aligned?
What I expect is:

[image]

But I had to use `<div class="row">` there, which is modifying margins (look at the label).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [form inline](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/forms/#inline-forms)

and don't forget to set `for` inside `label`

```html
<form class="form-inline">
    <label for="list_search">Search:</label>
    <input type="text" id="list_search" class="form-control">
    <button class="btn btn-info">Search</button>
</form>
```

GL